# Gerrit unable to replicate git repository

Tags: java, github, ssh, replication, gerrit

I am trying to get gerrit's github replication working. I am able to clone an empty repository directly using: git clone git@github.com:jpgrace/gerrit-test.git, but whenever I try to use gerrit to replicate anything, something fails. It doesn't matter if I run the replicate command via ssh or on the web app. I get the same error in the etc/error_log

If I run replication directly,

```
$ ssh -p 29418 jpgrace@ubuntu.vm gerrit replication start
```

this is the console output:

```
gerrit: replication: not found
```

and this written to the error_log:

```
[2014-05-12 18:47:30,785] ERROR com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.ReplicationQueue : Cannot replicate to git@github:jpgrace/All-Projects.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@github:jpgrace/All-Projects.git: unknown host
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:139)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.listRemote(PushOne.java:483)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.doPushAll(PushOne.java:427)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.generateUpdates(PushOne.java:420)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.pushVia(PushOne.java:368)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runImpl(PushOne.java:351)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.runPushOperation(PushOne.java:267)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.access$000(PushOne.java:78)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:240)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne$1.call(PushOne.java:237)
at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.PerThreadRequestScope$Propagator$1.call(PerThreadRequestScope.java:75)
at com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.replication.PushOne.run(PushOne.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:364)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Initially I thought that something wasn't right with my ssh config, or that I wasn't running gerrit under the gerrit user. One of the things that I don't understand is the "unknown hosts" part of the warning.

Here is my ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile /opt/gerrit/.ssh/id_rsa
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /opt/gerrit/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Here is the relavent output to "ps aux | grep gerrit"

```
gerrit    2546  1.7 35.4 1138240 177464 pts/2  Sl   17:45   0:53 GerritCodeReview -jar /opt/gerrit/bin/gerrit.war daemon -d /opt/gerrit --run-id=1399931125.2524
```

Here is my replication.config:

```
[remote "github"]
url = git@github:/${name}.git
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with the error message above. My replication.config was pointing at:

```
github
```

not:

```
github.com
```